# Why can't I access Forge APIs that use credits even though I have been assigned Forge via manage.autodesk.com?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I was trying to use the Model Derivative API in Postman but received the error:
"You are not allowed to use this API because your Forge trial is expired."
When I go to manage.autodesk.com I see that I am assigned the Forge product.
When I go to forge.autodesk.com and check my Forge Account Details, it says my free trial has expired and I can purchase additional credits. Do I not get credits from being assigned a Forge product from my company's account?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot get credits from your company's account as they are non-transferrable. Only the company's account will have the credits that can only be used by the app credentials of the company account.

[https://forge.autodesk.com/pricing#:~:text=Cloud%20Credits%20are%20aligned%20to,applied%20to%20any%20Forge%20API.&text=Forge%20subscriptions%20include%20access%20to,while%20your%20account%20is%20active.&text=Teams%20are%20standing%20by%20ready%20to%20help%20you%20with%20your%20Forge%20purchase.](https://forge.autodesk.com/pricing#:%7E:text=Cloud%20Credits%20are%20aligned%20to,applied%20to%20any%20Forge%20API.&text=Forge%20subscriptions%20include%20access%20to,while%20your%20account%20is%20active.&text=Teams%20are%20standing%20by%20ready%20to%20help%20you%20with%20your%20Forge%20purchase.)

[image: Forge API Usage T&C]